# Google plus share issues

Tags: html, google-app-engine, plugins, google-plus, blogger

I am getting an arrow icon while i share google plus blog:

https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://something.com&picture=http://www.somthing.com/image.jpg

Please see the share popup:

[image]

In the above picture you can see arrow marks (right and left) which i need to remove

I am not seeing anything in google plus share api to remove this?

Do you have any recommendation for this?

Comment: Did you refer this document? https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/article-rendering

Comment: yes , in that document arrow right left not appearing, but for me i am getting those arrow right left button

Comment: The [share link documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#share-link) doesn't support a `picture` parameter. Only `url` and `hl`.

Answer (score 1):

When you paste an URL, Google+ will automatically takes that image. In case if you have many images, you can just change the images at the top by just changing the left or right arrows to choose the exact image that you need.There seems to be no roundabout ways to remove that button.There is nothing in the Google plus share documentation too.